# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.springframework.web.reactive.function.client.DefaultExchangeStrategiesBuilder

Tags: spring, rest, spring-webflux, spring-webclient

I am trying to use spring `WebClient wc = WebClient.create();` in a **non-Spring application**, but it looks like DefaultExchangeStrategiesBuilder.DEFAULT_EXCHANGE_STRATEGIES returns null

```
causing error:
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.springframework.web.reactive.function.client.DefaultExchangeStrategiesBuilder
    at org.springframework.web.reactive.function.client.ExchangeStrategies.withDefaults(ExchangeStrategies.java:67)
    at org.springframework.web.reactive.function.client.DefaultWebClientBuilder.initExchangeStrategies(DefaultWebClientBuilder.java:302)
    at org.springframework.web.reactive.function.client.DefaultWebClientBuilder.build(DefaultWebClientBuilder.java:269)
    at org.springframework.web.reactive.function.client.WebClient.create(WebClient.java:144)
```

I have added to my POM:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-webflux</artifactId>
    <version>2.6.5</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: spring webclient is not a standalone http client, its a wrapper around the underlying client that the server implementation provides. For instance netty HttpClient or tomcat httpclient etc. So when you are saying NON spring application, what do you mean by that?

Comment: @Amigma do you have in your pom.xml as parent the `<parent>
  <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
  <version>2.6.5</version></parent` ?

Comment: No the app is not a Spring app., a legacy java struts web app, the WebClient is in a jar file which I include. The jar file's pom.xml also does not have that entry in its pom.xml either. I have used this jar in spring boot apps that use a weblogic server and it works fine so it must be getting dependencies it need from that. What does dependencies or settings does it need to be used in a NON-Spring app?

Answer (score 1):

If your application is not a Spring Boot application and does not apply Spring Boot's dependency management, you should not use Spring Boot's starters.

Instead you should use Spring Framework's `spring-webflux` dependency directly, as well as a client library of your choice, like [Reactor Netty, Jetty client, Apache HttpComponents](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/reference/html/web-reactive.html#webflux-client)...

You should also ensure that the Spring Framework BOM is applied to your project to avoid an incompatible mix of versions in your application:

```xml
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-framework-bom</artifactId>
  <version>...</version>
  <type>pom</type>
</dependency>
```